# Get Div Width then Update Scope Variable

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to limit the amount of text shown in a particular section of my angular app.

So I've set the `max-height` css variable however at times the `ng-bind` can return a lot of text which it shows regardless of having set that max height.

In my attempt to solve this I'm using the `limitTo` filter built into Angular, however the issue is as my page resizes, this `limitTo` value will also need change. (The wider the window the more text I can allow).

To get the width of the div I'm using

```
window.onload = function () {
  var availableWidth = document.getElementById('theJazz').clientWidth;
  if (availableWidth >= 500) {
    self.limitQuestionText = 80;
  } else {
    self.limitQuestionText = 50;
  }
}
```

However this poses 2 issues which I need help with:

1 - This variable won't be available until the page is completely loaded, thats why I'm using `window.onload = function ()`, however if the user resized the browser window the `availableWidth` would need to be changed. How do i do that.

2 - Then, the actual filter value: `limitQuestionText`, again I need to update once the page has loaded, is this actually allowed with filters? In that it doesn't seem to work in the same way as a usual scope variable updates without having to refresh the screen. And FYI - HTML looks like:

```
ng-bind-html="story.point | limitTo: main.limitQuestionText"
```

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up using this solution: https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner has abandoned the question with an outside reference to his solution without providing it here.

Comment: Stack Overflow encourages users to answer their own question. Be sure to include a code snippet and an explaination. A link-only answer is not useful to other readers if the link goes stale.

Comment: I found that solution however the 2 points in my question are still things I'm unclear on

Answer (score 2):

OK, the CSS/SCSS aproach from your comment looks good and that's probably the way to go.

Anyway with AngularJS I would create a directive to trigger a resize event handler that will update the `limitTo` filter scope value.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/k8bczrj9/).

**Remark**: The resizing is only working in SO if you open it in 'full page' mode.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('mainController', MainController)
 .directive('resize', ResizeDirective);
    
function MainController() {
 var vm = this;
    //console.log();
    //loading text from script tag (easier to write than inlined here)
    vm.limit = 50;
    vm.story = {
     point: document.getElementById('dummyText.txt').text
    };
}

function ResizeDirective($window, $timeout) {
 return {
     scope: {
         limit: '='
        },
     link: function(scope, elem) {
         var curWidth;
            function onResize(e) {
             curWidth = e.target.innerWidth;
                
                $timeout(function() {             
                    if ( curWidth >= 500 ) {
                  scope.limit = 80;
                    } else {
                        scope.limit = 50;
                    }

                    console.log(scope.limit);
                }, 0); // timeout = run with next digest / also scope.$apply() would be OK
             //console.log('resized', e);
            }
            
            // bind resize event
            angular.element($window).bind('resize', onResize);
            
            // dispatch event to trigger once at load to have the current width
            $window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
          
            scope.$on('$destory', function() {
             // remove resize handler if directive scope destroyed
             angular.element($window).unbind('resize', onResize);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: gray;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">

<pre>
    scope limit {{mainCtrl.limit}}
    cur. text length {{mainCtrl.limitedContent.length}}
</pre>
<div class="container" resize limit="mainCtrl.limit">
{{mainCtrl.limitedContent = (mainCtrl.story.point | limitTo: mainCtrl.limit)}}
</div>

<script type="text/plain" id="dummyText.txt">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: To prevent memory leaks, the `resize` directive needs to unbind the resize event handler when the directive scope is destroyed.